# SQLite Insert statement not executing command

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, sqlite

I have been running into problems before with my code, however I'm still unable to insert and save my statement into the database. When I enter a question into the database it will read back saying "Operation is not valid due to current state of the object"

```
    private void SubmitBttn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Reading User Question
            string userQuestionTxt = UsrQstnTxtBox.Text.ToString();
            string userQuestionID = QstnIDTextBx.Text.ToString();
            string userCourse = CourseDropBox.ToString();
            string userAnswr = User_Answr.ToString();

            //IF the question exists first 
            string SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM UserQuestion where QID = \'" + userQuestionID + "\'userQuestion = \'" + userQuestionTxt + "\'userCourse = \'" + userCourse + "\'";
            int returnCode = 0;
            MyQuestion.Clear();
            MyQuestion = dbMgr.GetData(SQLstr, out returnCode);

            //check for debug flag
            if (GlobalData.isDebug) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(SQLstr); }

            if (returnCode > 0)
            {
                string suggestion = "The question already exits in the database.";
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(suggestion, "Add Question");
                return;
            }
            //Insert Query
             SQLstr = "INSERT INTO UserQuestion (Course, QID , userQuestion, AnswrID, UserAnswr) " +
                        "VALUES ('" + userCourse + "," + userQuestionID + "," + userQuestionTxt + "," + User_Answr + "')";

            //Checking for debug flag
            if (GlobalData.isDebug) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(SQLstr); }

            int numRowsModified = 0;
            numRowsModified = dbMgr.PutData(SQLstr);

            if (numRowsModified > 0)
            {
                string greeting = "Question Posted.";
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(greeting, "Add Question");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Question has not been added.");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String msg = ex.Message.ToString() + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Gluing data into a SQL string query is absolutely the wrong way to build SQL.  Always use SQL Parameters. The rest of your problem is somewhere in that DB "helper" - where the actual execute statement is

Comment: As @Disaffected1070452 said, never create a query through string concatenation. If you switch to a parameterized query, you will solve your problem. In the short term, you would need literal single-quotes around *each* value in the `VALUES` clause (but don't do that, change to a parameterized query). Short term fix is `VALUES ('" + first + "', '" + second + "', '" + ...` quoting each parameter.

Comment: @BobKaufman agreed, but there's a simple work around without parameterizing.  You can just replace any single quotes with 2 single quotes VALUES ('" + Regex.Replace(first, "'", "''") + "', '" + ....

Comment: Also, it's not like I can sneak injection into an int (assuming userQuestionID is an int) so the quotes and parameters arent always necessary

Comment: Changing the data - such as `O'Hare` to `O''Hare` is not a reasonable solution.  How would searching work?  Would personal names be mutilated the same way?  Always use SQL Parameters. Always.